# Android. При запуске на устройстве с длинным экраном приложение отрисовывается черная область снизу

Tags: android

Устройство Poco F3, повторяется и на других устройствах с длинным экраном. Приложение занимает не весь экран. Появляется черная область снизу.

minSdkVersion 21

targetSdkVersion 30

Проект старый, но таргет поднят до актуального. Используется AndroidX. При создании нового пустого проекта с абсолютно таким же AndroidManifest проблема не повторяется. **Из-за чего такое происходит?**

Пример пустого активити без макета, показывающее проблему, представлен на скриншоте. Если будет макет, то он занимает только белую область. Черная область так и остается.

[image: вСкриншот пустого activity]

Comment: Что displayMetrics говорит? Какой у него aspectRatio? Может у вас это в приложении выставлено?  https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#maxaspectratio

Comment: Разметку показывайте.